# Is there a way in Windows 10 to create a list of files along with any file tags?

Tags: command-line

I'm trying to find out which of my pictures are not tagged. I've seen the DOS command list, but that didn't show how to display file tags. [Dos Commands](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/cc755121(v=ws.11))

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "not tagged"?

Comment: Think about using PowerShell and Get-Item command. If there are tags assigned to files. The main question is: where you see these tags?

Comment: Super coincidence :) I use mobile so I can't see new comments immediately.

Comment: Ah ok - I'd look at exiftool, you need to filter by Meta Data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your folder, select "Details" as the view type, and order by Tags:

[image]

You can then group by the tags to easily see which aren't tagged and which are. Click on View, then Group by and choose Tags.

[image: GroupBy]

Comment: Thanks. This will certainly help me to see what is tagged, and what is not. Thanks.